# How much more quickly do Deviant weapons charge Hunter Arts?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

The whole gimmick of weapons made from Deviant monsters is that they charge Hunter Arts more quickly. Exactly how much more quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this with the Switch Axe art Energy Charge II.

With a normal weapon, it takes 12 hits in sword mode to fully charge it.

With a Deviant weapon, it only takes 10 hits.

The amount of charge X gained from each hit of a Deviant weapon can thus be calculated:

- 10*X = 12*Y (this is when both weapons reach full charge)
- 10/12 = Y/X
- X/Y = 12/10
- X = 120% Y

The result seems to be that Hunter Arts charge **20% more quickly**.